# How can I make a loop in swich case(swift)?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, loops, boolean

I wrote that code but I cannot make a loop in false condition. How can I make a loop for false condition?

Note: "isConnectedToNetwork()" returns a boolean expression.

```
switch Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() {
    case false :
        println("Internet connection FAILED")
        var alert = UIAlertView(title: "No Internet Connection", message: "Make sure your device is connected to the internet.", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
        alert.show()
        fallthrough
     default:
         println(“Internet connection OK")
}
```

Comment: If it’s a boolean why don’t you just use `if(Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork(){print internet ok}else{show alert}`

Comment: I would reread everything you read on switch statements. Adding fallthrough on a switch that handles a boolean is a bit strange. At the moment when it is false, it will also execute the default. Also there is no loop anywhere in your code. Switch statements are about as far from loops as you can get since they execute the first matching case once. If you need a loop, use while or do while

Comment: You need to implement the reachability callbacks if you want to get notified when it changes: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while !Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() {
   println("Internet connection FAILED")
   var alert = UIAlertView(title: "No Internet Connection", message: "Make sure your device is connected to the internet.", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
   alert.show()
}
println("Internet connection OK")
```

While this answers your question, it is a truly terrible idea. Please don't actually use this in any application, instead you need to implement [reachability callbacks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) as suggested by @i_am_jorf, or rethink the design of this code